# List containing class objects not working

Tags: c#, list, class

I am working on a small C# program that will store student records in a list. I need to use a class to hold each student record, which is the top class in my code sample below.

If the user chooses to create a new record, I place their input into a `studentRecord` variable and then add it to the `recordList`. However, when I attempt to display the number of student records currently available using `Count()`, the program does nothing except re-display the menu, as if totally ignoring my command to display. I think something is wrong with how/where I declared the list, or with how I create a new `StudentRecord` object each time the menu is run.

Also, all three methods must stay in the first class. Is there any way to fix this?

```
public class StudentRecord
{
    //Declare the various fields of the class
    private string strFirstName;
    private string strLastName;
    private int intCourses;
    private int intCreditHours;

    List<StudentRecord> lstRecords = new List<StudentRecord>();

    //Declare the properties of the class, since the fields are private
    public string StrFirstName
    {
        get
        {
            return strFirstName;
        }
        set
        {
            strFirstName = value;
        }
    }

    public string StrLastName
    {
        get
        {
            return strLastName;
        }
        set
        {
            strLastName = value;
        }
    }

    public int IntCourses
    {
        get
        {
            return intCourses;
        }
        set
        {
            intCourses = value;
        }
    }

    public int IntCreditHours
    {
        get
        {
            return intCreditHours;
        }
        set
        {
            intCreditHours = value;
        }
    }


    //Declare a default constructor
    public StudentRecord()
    {            
    }

    //Declare a constructor that takes the four necessary parameters, and set the class
    //  properties equal to the respective parameters
    public StudentRecord(string firstName, string lastName, int courses, int creditHours)
    {
        strFirstName = firstName;
        strLastName = lastName;
        intCourses = courses;
        intCreditHours = creditHours;
    }


    //Declare a method to perform the adding a student record function
    public void mtdAddStudentRecord()
    {
        //These variables temporarily hold the various user inputs
        string strInputFirstName;
        string strInputLastName;
        int intInputCourses;
        int intInputCreditHours;


        //Prompt the user to enter the student's first name
        Console.Write("Please enter the first name:    ");
        strInputFirstName = Console.ReadLine();


        //Prompt the user to enter the student's last name
        Console.Write("Please enter the last name:    ");
        strInputLastName = Console.ReadLine();

        //Prompt the user to enter the student's number of courses
        Console.Write("Please enter the number of courses:    ");
        intInputCourses = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        //Prompt the user to enter the student's completed credit hours
        Console.Write("Please enter the number of completed credit hours:    ");
        intInputCreditHours = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


        //Add the new student record to the list, using the paramaters of the second
        //  class constructor
        lstRecords.Add(new StudentRecord(strInputFirstName, strInputLastName,
            intInputCourses, intInputCreditHours));
    }


    //Declare a method to perform the display student information option
    public void mtdDisplayStudentInformation()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Capacity: {0}", lstRecords.Count);
    }


    //Declare a method to perform the edit student information option
    public void mtdEditStudentInformation()
    {
        //TODO
    }

}




public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Declare and initialize a variable to store the user menu choice
        string strMenuChoice;
        strMenuChoice = "";


        //Perform the necessary menu option while the user has NOT chosen to exit
        do
        {
            //Call the reset method to clear the screen and display the header
            mtdResetConsole();

            //Display a menu to the user
            Console.Write("Please choose an option to perform:" +
                "\n   - A) Display a list of existing students" +
                "\n   - B) Add a new student record" +
                "\n   - C) Edit an existing student record" +
                "\n   - D) Exit the program" + "\n\n" + "     ");

            //Store the user reply
            strMenuChoice = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();


            //Create a new StudentRecord object, and use it to call the various methods
            //  as chosen by the user
            StudentRecord studentRecord = new StudentRecord();

            //Determine which option was chosen, and take the appropriate action
            switch (strMenuChoice)
            {
                case "a":
                    //TODO - Necessary code for option A
                    mtdResetConsole();

                    //Perform the "view student records" method
                    studentRecord.mtdDisplayStudentInformation();

                    break;

                case "b":
                    //TODO - Necessary code for option B
                    mtdResetConsole();

                    //Perform the "add student record" method
                    studentRecord.mtdAddStudentRecord();                        

                    break;

                case "c":
                    //TODO - Necessary code for option C
                    break;

                case "d":
                    //Exit the program
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                    break;

                default:
                    mtdResetConsole();
                    Console.WriteLine("Error" + "\n" +
                        "   - Please choose a valid option from the list");

                    //Pause the code from executing for 2.5 seconds, so that the error
                    //  message will be displayed
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2500);

                    break;
            }
        }
        while (strMenuChoice.ToLower() != "d");
    }



    //Declare a method to reset the console with a blank screen and header
    public static void mtdResetConsole()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("CONESTOGA STUDENT RECORDS" + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you point out the line in question that's giving you an issue? Where you trying to display the student records currently available? It seems like you're doing that with mtdDisplayStudentInformation - is that correct?

Comment: One issue you have is `lstRecords` is declared as an instance field, meaning every single instance of `StudentRecord` will have it's only separate list. If you declare it as `static` or move it outside of the `StudentRecord` class, then you will have one list.

Comment: StudentRecord studentRecord = new StudentRecord(); this line should be placed outside of do-while loop.

Comment: @Karata Thanks to both of you! You are right...I have now moved the list declaration outside of the 'do-while loop'. I am new to OOP, and forgot that it would re-declare a new separate list for each class object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, put this outside do while

```
    StudentRecord studentRecord = new StudentRecord();
```

Putting this inside do while means that the object will reset in every loop.

2nd, try to put something like Console.ReadLine() on mtdDisplayStudentInformation method to hold the screen.

```
    public void mtdDisplayStudentInformation()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Capacity: {0}", lstRecords.Count);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: I appreciate this very much! You were absolutely correct. I have just moved the studentRecord call outside of the do-while loop, and it is running fine. And yes, I do have something for the user input. I merely used capacity as a shortcut to see if it would work. The real program has a foreach loop that iterates over each student, and displays their information. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Kendall, try to separate the logic of your "Records" and your "List of records". 
In the case bellow, you have a "list of records" for each record you create.

Suggestions are you create a static variable to make sure it is always the same list on all "Records" or you separate as bellow:

```
public class StudentRecord
{
     //Declare the various fields of the class
    private string strFirstName;
    private string strLastName;
    private int intCourses;
    private int intCreditHours;
...
}

public class Program
{
     private List<StudentRecord> records = new List<StudentRecord>();
     public static void Main(string[] args)
     {
        ...
     }
}
```